# SVG gradient offset animation

Tags: svg, offset, linear-gradients, svg-animate

I'm working on an SVG animation. But I've encountered a problem... I want to animate a changing gradient offset in my SVG. I use this SVG for this. I have already animated changing colors animation but I can't change the offset of the gradient.

```html
<svg className="SvgContain" width="923" height="382" viewBox="0 0 923 382" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs>
  <linearGradient id="gradient1">
     <stop className="stop1" offset="0%" stop-color="red">
     </stop>
     <stop className="stop2" offset="100%" stop-color="blue">
     </stop>
  </linearGradient>
   </defs>
   <path className="SvgPath" id="PolygonePath" d="M0.5 381.5L382 0H923V381.5H0.5Z" fill="url(#gradient1)">
</svg>
```

I tried to use the <animate></animate> tag for creating the effect want to do but it doesn't work.
I used this code for this. I asked ChatGPT if the animate tag can handle the animation of the offset. It says yes, I followed the instructions but the animation didn't work.

```html
<svg className="SvgContain" width="923" height="382" viewBox="0 0 923 382" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs>
  <linearGradient id="gradient1">
     <stop className="stop1" offset="0%" stop-color="red">
        <animate
          attributeName="offset"
          values="0%; 100%"
          dur="5s"
          repeatCount="indefinite">
        </animate>
     </stop>
     <stop className="stop2" offset="100%" stop-color="blue">
        <animate
          attributeName="offset"
          values="100%; 0%"
          dur="5s"
          repeatCount="indefinite">
        </animate>
     </stop>
  </linearGradient>
   </defs>
   <path className="SvgPath" id="PolygonePath" d="M0.5 381.5L382 0H923V381.5H0.5Z" fill="url(#gradient1)">
</svg>
```

Comment: 1. It's stop-color not color. 2. Try using `values="0; 1"` instead of percentages

Comment: @exaneta values="0;1" should be exactly the same as "0%; 100%"

Comment: @RobertLongson i change all "color" by "stop-color" the color appear right when i don't use the animate balise. But when i use the <animate></animate> balise something wrong is result.

Comment: Now it says stop-color and animates, is there anything else wrong? If so what exactly do you want it to look like. Note that [stop offset values must be in order](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#GradientStops) *Each gradient offset value is required to be equal to or greater than the previous gradient stop's offset value. If a given gradient stop's offset value is not equal to or greater than all previous offset values, then the offset value is adjusted to be equal to the largest of all previous offset values.* So your animation won't really be a gradient after you get to 50%

Comment: @RobertLongson  i mean tags, sorry. thank you for your explanations... with it I saw a behavior of degraders that I was unaware of. This didn't produce the desired result but it will help me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the animation you meant... Take a look at these two methods. I assume using `JS` is not the problem. In my opinion, this is a better solution because you can control the animation more. Below is a variant with `JS` and `CSS`. The `CSS` is a bit *wild* but it's a matter of adjusting the frames.

JS option:

```js
const stop1 = document.getElementById('stop1');
let offset = 0;
let speed = 0.2;
let direction = 1;

const animateGradient = () => {
  offset += speed * direction;
  
  if (offset >= 100 || offset <= 0) {
    direction *= -1; 
  }
  stop1.setAttribute('offset', `${offset}%`);
 requestAnimationFrame(animateGradient);
}
animateGradient();
```

```css
.SvgContain {
      width: 923px;
      height: 382px;
    }
```

```html
<svg class="SvgContain" viewBox="0 0 923 382" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="-50%" y1="0%" x2="150%" y2="0%">
      <stop id="stop1" offset="0%" stop-color="red"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path class="SvgPath" id="PolygonePath" d="M0.5 381.5L382 0H923V381.5H0.5Z" fill="url(#gradient1)"></path>
</svg>
```

As you can see, there is a line at the *junction* of the colors, it doesn't look good, you can manipulate the number of stops to spread the color spectrum.

CSS option

```css
@keyframes moveGradient1 {
  0%, 100% {
    stop-color: red;
    offset: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    stop-color: blue;
    offset: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes moveGradient2 {
  0%, 100% {
    stop-color: blue;
    offset: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    stop-color: red;
    offset: 0%;
  }
}
.stop1 {
  animation: moveGradient1 4s linear infinite;
}
.stop2 {
  animation: moveGradient2 4s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg class="SvgContain" width="923" height="382" viewBox="0 0 923 382" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient1">
      <stop class="stop1" offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop class="stop2" offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path class="SvgPath" id="PolygonePath" d="M0.5 381.5L382 0H923V381.5H0.5Z" fill="url(#gradient1)"></path>
</svg>
```